# Type issue writing a short HtmlHelper DropDownList overloaded method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am trying to overload the DropDownListFor HtmlHelper method.

Typically, the parameter 'htmlAttributes' would be an anonymous object. If the htmlAttributes was not already a RouteValueDictionary, I would convert it to this type for the purpose of modifying the collection as needed, based upon custom logic that I would add, such as handling disabling the control based on the value of the "disabled" parameter value, as just one example.

```
    public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(
            this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
            Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, 
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, 
            string optionLabel, 
            object htmlAttributes,
            bool disabled)
    {
        if (!(htmlAttributes is RouteValueDictionary))
        {
            htmlAttributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        }
        else
        {
            htmlAttributes = (RouteValueDictionary)htmlAttributes;
        }

        if (disabled)
        {
            //manipulate the htmlAttributes collection here                     
        }
        return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, selectList, optionLabel, htmlAttributes);
    }
```

I am running into a problem when I call the "native" System.Web.Mvc.Html.DropDownListFor in the last line. It does not correctly handle the htmlAttributes being of type "RouteAttributes" when it expected an Anonymous object. As a result, I get HTML that does not properly convert the name/value html attributes of the routingAttributes collection to nanme/value HTML attribute pairs. I get this (note the Keys and Values properties):

For example, when I call it with this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FrequencyCode, Model.FrequencyCodes.ToListOfSelectListItem(Model.FrequencyCode), "", new { @class = "form-control" }, true)
```

I get this:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="Frequency is required" id="FrequencyCode" name="FrequencyCode" type="hidden" value="" />
<select Count="1" Keys="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.Object]" Values="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,System.Object]" id="FrequencyCode" name="FrequencyCode">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="A">ANNUAL</option>
<option value="M">MONTHLY</option>
<option value="Q">QUARTERLY</option>
</select>
```

It seems one way to fix this would be if I could convert the object of type RouteDictionary  back to an anonymous object. How do I do this? Is there a better way?

Comment: I needed to cast htmlAttributes as a RouteValueDictionary or use a temporary variable of type RouteValueDictionary. Someone put this as an answer, plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method for solving this is to have multiple overloads, just as the in-build `HtmlHelper` methods do (refer the [source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs) for the `DropDownListFor()` methods).

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, 
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, 
        string optionLabel, 
        IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes,
        bool disabled)

public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, 
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, 
        string optionLabel, 
        object htmlAttributes,
        bool disabled)
```

However, generating a disabled `<select>` element does not make a lot of sense - you generating a lot of extra unnecessary html, and disabled controls do not submit there value so model binding may fail, and if the method is binding to a property which is value type, or has validation attributes, `ModelState` will be invalid. A better approach would be to display just the selected text value and a hidden input (assuming you want to post the value).

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, string optionLabel, object htmlAttributes, bool disabled)
{
    if (disabled)
    {
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        // add a hidden input
        html.Append(htmlHelper.HiddenFor(expression).ToString());
        // Get the display text
        ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        string value = metaData.Model.ToString();
        var displayText = selectList.Where(x => x.Value == value).Select(x => x.Text).FirstOrDefault();
        TagBuilder div = new TagBuilder("div");
        div.AddCssClass("readonly");
        div.InnerHtml = displayText;
        html.Append(div.ToString());
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(html.ToString());
    }
    return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, selectList, optionLabel, htmlAttributes);
}
```

and then use css to style `.readonly` to look like a `<input />` or `<select>` element if that's what you want.

Comment: Does adding a disabled attribute to a div provide any benefit? Why not just have a disabled textbox by itself? That value will post even disabled. If you take this approach, do you lose the flexibility to enable the dropdown from client script? Ah, must be the desired appearance. How is the non static class ModelMetaData accessible from the HtmlHelper, which is part of a WebViewPage? Voted Up...

Comment: A `<div>` cannot have a disabled attribute (its not valid html). If you do want to be able to enable the dropdown in javascript, then this approach would not be suitable and you would need to generate the `<select>` (but then again, you face the issue of the value not posting back and possibly causing problems on the server - although there are some workarounds such as also including a hidden input). Not sure what you mean by the 3rd item

Comment: You could have a readonly textbox instead of a `<div>` but that contains the text of the selected option, so you still need a hidden input for the value - so therefore it would just be creating a bit of extra unnecessary html (the `<div>` is just a bit more efficient).

Comment: _That value will post even disabled_ No it wont. Disabled controls never submit their value.

Comment: Re: A <div> cannot have a disabled attribute (its not valid html). Is this what you did? : div.AddCssClass("readonly");

Comment: That's adding a class name - so it renders `<div class="readonly">yourValue</div>` - and then you can style the div using css to look like an input with borders etc. Its not the same as adding `disabled="disabled"` which is only applicable to form controls (input, textarea, select)